# Base SDK Missing xcode 4.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I used OSX 10.7.4 , Xcode 4.3.3 and iPad iOS 5.1.1 . I already run my app to iPad but the app cannot be open. i find out that my Xcode is base sdk missing. i also don't have the folder that can select to simulator. there's only folder for MacOSX10.4u.sdk MacOSX10.5u.sdk MacOSX10.6u.sdk only. How can i run my app perfectly.

**Update:**

this is the problem

[image]

and there's no iOS sdk

[image]

Comment: I've updated your original question with your screen snapshots. But when I look at these screen snapshots, they don't look like Xcode 4.3.3! All of the icons and menus are different than my screen (though the window behind the active screen on your first screen snapshot looks like mine). But I don't recognize your smaller Heritage.xcodeproj windows. Are you sure you're looking at this in Xcode 4.3.3? I don't doubt that you have Xcode 4.3.3 installed, but might you have another version lingering about?

Answer (score 0):

Head to your Project Settings, and under 'Summary' change 'Deployment Target' to whatever you like (say, '5.0'). If that doesn't work, select 'Manage Schemes' via the 'Product' menu and then 'Autocreate Schemes Now'.

Comment: it still showed base sdk missing. and i cannot find 'summary'. where can i find the 'summary and deployment target'?

Answer (score 0):

Is this either one of your old projects or even some project you got from somewhere else (including even the sample projects that Apple provides)? You can fix this "Missing Base SDK" by selecting the project on the top of the panel on the left (in this example, it's one of Apple's samples, "Recipes", and then click on the "Validate Settings" button:

[image]

After doing that, you'll probably get a message about updating your project. Go ahead and you should be good:

[image]

If you just created the project, then it's something else. But this is the most common scenario for "missing base SDK".

Comment: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)

Comment: @WafaaHapiz 1. Do I assume correctly that you've fixed the "Missing Base SDK" error? 2. Can you run it on the simulator? (i.e. in that box labeled "scheme" up in the upper left corner, you have a choice between running it on a device or running it on a simulator; try running it on the simulator). I assume you're trying to run this on a device but have not gotten your developer certificate installed yet. But let's see if you can get it to run on the simulator first.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a solution for XCode 3.2.6 but other answers did not seem to apply. Further experimentation found that Project -> Edit Active Target and then setting Base SDK on that page was just what I needed. Hope this helps the next guy that stumbles through.